# Array Formula - Hide zero until data is entered -

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to hide the zero for R4 until I input the data.
R4 it's an array formula - R4 (Plan) sums and updates F through Q based on when data for row 5 comes (Act.)

When the data comes, IF THE RESULT IS STILL "0" THEN THE ZERO SHOULD DISPLAY.

SO.. hide zero until data comes, if the result is 0 when data comes, that has to show.

I feel dumb - I don't know how to accomplish this with the array formula in place.
I tried conditional formatting =IF(OR - also (IF(ISBLANK but couldn't figure it out

R5 - I'm using =IF(COUNTA(F5:Q5)>0,SUM(F5:Q5),"") - No array formula there, I was using a simple SUM formula before, and I changed it to =IF(COUNTA to hide the zero.

Also, cannot use ;;; or other variation under number format to hide the zero, not an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF(ISBLANK(F5:Q5),"",<your array formula>)` then close it as array formula.

Note that if any cell from the `F5:Q5` range is filled the value will show, if you want to display it only when all the range is filled you can do:

```
IF(SUM(ISBLANK(F5:Q5)+0)>0,"",<your array formula>)
```

Or if you don't like the `+0` hack to convert the boolean to number you could use `VALUE` function instead.

Comment: The first one worked perfectly. Thank you!